# How to prevent a filter in the UI from affecting one of my tables

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I have the following problem.

I have a Data Set A in which I have created several charts with their tables.

There is a filter panel at the top where any change you make to these filters is reflected in the tables and graphics below.

Nowadays I want to create a table which in the saql statement will work with filters like current day or current month and I do not want this table to be affected by the filters that appear above, know if there is any way to tell a filter that only affects certain tables and not all?

I appreciate your possible help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I do not know if it's the best, Create a DataSet B that is a clone of the DataSet A and note that the UI filters are only applied in the DataSetA and not in B. So this is what I needed.